# List all unique associations active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a class named Job and one named Hour

Job has many Hours

At some point I have selected a collection of Hours. Now I want to get a list of all the Jobs these hours belongs to.

Comment: If job has_many hours, hour belong to job. Therefore, all hours will only belong to one job. Doesn't seem to be the model you want. Why don't you try to redefine your stuff with has_and_belongs_to_many$?

Comment: You are right that Hour only belongs to one Job but I am querying my hours based on another attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to get hours.

If your collection is on AR relation then you can do this

```
<hours collection>.includes(:job).map(&:job)
```

If it is array of hours then simply do

```
<hours collection>.map(&:job)
```

You can also achieve this in sub query(hours collection should be on AR relation)

```
Job.includes(:hours).where(:id => <hours collection>.select("job_id"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was on the includes thing but the map thing is new to me.